# How can i set include path of boost for all C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio, boost, include-path

is there any way to set boost path for all C++ projects and don't do it in feature for any project which we create ?!

i search in VS tools and google it but there wasn't such same idea for doing it .

`include <boost/example/example.hpp>`

Comment: `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/boost` in Linux with GCC.

Comment: Do you mean like, [create a custom template](https://rehansaeed.com/custom-visual-studio-project-templates/)?

Comment: @lakeweb no
i mean set default path of boost for all new apps that we will create !